# How can I get a Django foreignkey using a TextInput widget to display a name, rather than an id?

Tags: django, django-forms

I have the following (simplified for this example) Django models:

```
class Ingredient(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class RecipeIngredient(models.Model):
    quantity = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=3)
    unit_of_measure = models.ForeignKey(UnitOfMeasure)
    ingredient = models.ForeignKey(Ingredient)
    comment = models.CharField(max_length = 40, blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.id
```

And I have the following form:

```
class RecipeIngredientForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = RecipeIngredient

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(RecipeIngredientForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['quantity'].widget = forms.TextInput(attrs={'size':'6'})
        self.fields['ingredient'].widget = forms.TextInput(attrs={'size':'30'})
        self.fields['comment'].widget = forms.TextInput(attrs={'size':'38'})
```

When I view the form, the ingredient is displayed by its id value, not its name.  How can I display the name, rather than the id?

UPDATE

A solution (more elegant ideas still welcome) is to subclass the TextInput widget and use the value to get the Ingredient name:

```
class IngredientInput(forms.TextInput):
    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None):
        new=Ingredient.objects.get(pk=value).name
        value=new
        if value is None:
            value = ''
        final_attrs = self.build_attrs(attrs, type=self.input_type, name=name)
        if value != '':
            # Only add the 'value' attribute if a value is non-empty.
            final_attrs['value'] = force_unicode(self._format_value(value))
        return mark_safe(u'<input%s />' % flatatt(final_attrs))
```

Answer (score 4):

I solved this use case by overriding a field's queryset within `__init__` on the Form. A select input is still displayed but it only has one option. I had the same issue as the OP by too many options for the select.

```
class PaymentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PaymentForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        instance = kwargs.get("instance", None)

        if instance and instance.id and instance.reconciled_by:
            self.fields["reconciled_by"].queryset = User.objects.filter(
                id=instance.reconciled_by.id
            )
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and solved very similarly like this (Python 3) this also used the super class to do the rendering rather than rewriting it out again. 
I have added a feature which I wanted which is to make the field read only, I left it it as I thought it might be useful for editing for what you want:

```
class IngredientInput(forms.TextInput):

   def render(self, name, value, attrs=None):
        new=Ingredient.objects.get(pk=value).name
        value = self._format_value(new)
        attrs['readonly'] = True
        return super(IngredientInput, self).render(name, value, attrs)
```

Answer (score -1):

IT displays the id because you said so:

```
class RecipeIngredient(models.Model):
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.id
```

EDIT:

...and also, because you use a TextInput

```
self.fields['ingredient'].widget = forms.TextInput(attrs={'size':'30'})
```

I guess you need this:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking that, but changing it to self.name, or self.ingredient or self.ingredient.name or commenting it out entirely has no effect.  Is there some other way I can use the __unicode__ value?

Comment: I had to move away from modelchoicefields for perfomance reasons (way too many ingredient choices for a drop down).  Hence, I've moved to the TextInput widget instead.

Comment: Further data point.  If I comment out the self.fields['ingredient'].widget line and change the unicode definition for Ingredient, it changes what I get in the resulting Select widget dropdown.  This means that the Ingredient unicode definition dictates what appears in that widget, not the RecipeIngredient unicode definition.  I assume this means that when I change the widget to TextInput I'm severing the tie back to the unicode definition somehow.